# Azure function occasionally runs twice

Tags: azure-functions

I have a Powershell function running on a timer that runs once a week at 8am Monday morning - it sends out emails.  It works fine most of the time, but every once in a while it runs twice:

[image]

The second instance ran at the exact time the first one finished.

I've googled the problem and most of the articles out there centre around having **runatstartup=true**.  I've never set that anywhere and have checked the function app configuration and the function.json and can't find any mention of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices#write-functions-to-be-stateless)

> ### Write functions to be stateless
>
> Functions should be stateless and
> idempotent if possible. Associate any required state information with
> your data. For example, an order being processed would likely have an
> associated state member. A function could process an order based on
> that state while the function itself remains stateless.
>
> Idempotent functions are especially recommended with **timer triggers**.
> For example, if you have something that absolutely must run once a
> day, write it so it can run anytime during the day with the same
> results. The function can exit when there's no work for a particular
> day. Also if a previous run failed to complete, **the next run should
> pick up where it left off.**

You should probably also read the [wiki about reentrancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing))

[Azure functions guarantees at least once messaging, so multiple executions are possible in certain (though hopefully rare) situations.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/386#issuecomment-408919224)

For your problem this would mean, keeping track of the emails that are deliverd. Somewhere out of the function runtime (I.e.: storage account). When the function starts in the same day or week (depending on your requirements) start from the where it left of.

The reason this is a best practice. Since you are running jobs anything can happen when running your code. The server can crash, network can go down, your function could be moved to a different host, patching, ...